# How do I open and display a file with any file extension in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a program where I have to read information from a file and it can be a file with any extension.  Do you know any way in C++ to read and display the information from a file different than the .txt extension?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Depends on the OS. In Windows the general file presentation functionality was introduced in Windows 95, and discontinued after Windows 98 I think it was. It used the `dumpbin` header dump result as presentation of executables.

Comment: In a few 10's of seconds, using a browser, I searched for "linux dump file in hex" and found several generic tools already on my Lubuntu system ... including od and xxd.  Use them and the many others to see the hex contents of a file, then study the format specs, and start working on a C++ decoder.  Have fun.

Comment: use file handling for this

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no real difference that would be made by a file extension, so you can - in theory - open any file you want, for example by using std::ifstream. However, files that are not using a human-readable encoding (like txt/json/... files), you propably want to open it in binary mode (you can specify this to std::ifstream).

However, if you actually want some usefull information of some specific, not human readable file (like for example the dimensions of a images saved as a png file), you need way more detailled code. To read, for example, information from an png file, you have to open it in binary mode using std::ifstream, and then interpret the read bytes yourself to get any usefull information out of it. So you actually have to know how the specific file format you want to read is encoded, and need to have (or to implement yourself) a decoder for that specific file format.